# Is it legal for a developer to claim ownership of a clients' analytics data?

Tags: google-analytics, legal

We are working with a client who is having his analytics data held hostage by his previous developers. They are claiming that their contract states that they own the data, but I'm wondering if showing ownership of the site might be enough to stop them from holding the data hostage. Does anyone know if our client has any leverage against the claims of his previous developers??

I'm a bit worried that a contract DOES have the power to lock a client out of that data, but it just seems... criminal... for someone to do that to a client.

Comment: im not sure if this helps, but if the data is google analytics (or any other) id check in the terms and conditions of the analytics package who to see who owns the data. I wouldnt be surprised if google owns the data .. and just lends it to you (not saying it does but worth checking). But you'd have to read the t&c of the analytics package your using

Comment: Did they use his or their analytics account?

Comment: If they signed a contract saying that they own the analytics data then I would think that they own it...

Comment: `Hostage` sounds so dramatic. Sounds like the previous developers did not get paid. Tell your client to pay his outstanding invoice.

Comment: Is there actually a contract? What does it say? Did all parties sign that? Go get the lawyers if anyone disagrees with the contract. End of discussion. Nobody here can help you.

Comment: I agree with @Su' get a lawyer, the contracts don't matter much to be honest most are boiler plate and an attorney once paid will go fight for the data regardless of what's in the contract they'll look for anything to find a loophole in it. Just because someone signed a contract doesn't prevent anyone from going to court.

Comment: Also if it's data in a Google Analytics account it's not their data it's technically Google's so you should contact Google's Analytics team by phone and explain the situation.

Answer (score 0):

What difference does it make if it's legal? Possession is 9/10 of the law. I think there is a way to recover the data, I saw it about two years ago. search for "reclaim Google analytics" . or you may want to negotiate with them. It's probably fastness just to negotiate with them.